# How to get more detail than "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to"

Tags: google-chrome, internet-connection

Latest version of Chrome seems to give extremely limited information on what might be wrong. It only says:

```
"Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to"
```

It used to have error codes and so on.

How can I get Chrome to tell me more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the newer-style friendly error messages like this (from google's help pages):

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings
3. Click Show advanced settings and find the "Privacy" section.
4. Deselect the "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors" checkbox to
   disable the feature. Select the checkbox to enable it again.

Then when you visit a host which can't be found in DNS or a host which is not responding to http requests, you will get the option to choose "more" to see a little more information.